# Populate UICollectionView with images from CoreData

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimage, loading

I am trying to populate my UICollectionView with my data from CoreData database. The problem is that I want to show a photo in Collection Cell and using data to create UIImage - this task can take a while. With the current solution the images are loaded approx. after 3 seconds but all the other data is already shown in collection view.

**How should I add the loading overlay and know when all the images are ready to hide it, or what is correct approach?**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: viewModel.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? LocationCollectionViewCell {
    
        cell.name.text = viewModel.locations[indexPath.row].name
        cell.unlocked.text = viewModel.locations[indexPath.row].unlocked ? "Unlocked" : "Locked"
        
        if let data = viewModel.locations[indexPath.row].image {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.image.image = self.viewModel.locations[indexPath.row].unlocked ? image : image?.grayscale()
                }
            }
        } else {
            cell.image.image = viewModel.locations[indexPath.row].unlocked ? UIImage(named: "noun_Akropolis_403786") : UIImage(named: "noun_Akropolis_403786")?.grayscale()
        }
        
        return cell
        
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: viewModel.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add loader in cell and show/hide it when image is nil or not

Comment: This can be per cell right? Is there any chance to use one overlay over the whole screen either (for this I need to know if all cells are ready)?

Comment: Yess do you mean like shimmer effect?

Comment: You can add loader in whole screen as well.

Comment: For that create an array where when any image is loaded just append that index there. Until array doesnt contain all index show loader in screen else hide loader.

Comment: Okay, got it. But what about error handling? I mean, there is a lot of things that can happen - image will not be loaded, not appended, then index will be out of range, etc. What I need to do, is basically take the locations array, for each location take the image data, create UIImage, append it to new array and then set the cell.image to the imageArray[indexPath.row], right? And loading will be shown until the whole imageArray is not ready.

Comment: Yeah you are doing good. And For handling error you can simply use try catch. If image is not loading or it is falied then you shouldn provide dummy or placeholder image. So that loader will be removed at one time.

Comment: Great, will do! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Is that working @peter?

Comment: Yes, I've decided to use activity indicator on each cell, it's better :) Everything works as expected. Maybe I will add some caching as well.

Comment: Please mark my answer correct. and if possible upvote me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @peter you can try follow things:

1. You can add loader in cell and show/hide it when image is nil or not.
2. For that create an array where when any image is loaded just append that index there. Until array doesnt contain all index show loader in screen else hide loader.
3. For handling error you can simply use try catch. If image is not loading or it is falied then you shouldn provide dummy or placeholder image. So that loader will be removed at one time.

Comment: One additional question, how can I get rid of the unresponsive collectionView while loading images? For example I have 5 images, 4 are already loaded and one still loading - I cannot move or scroll with collectionView even when I am running task on backgroun (to load UIImage from data) and putting in on main thread only for assign image=imageFromData ? I am expecting to have collection view in same behavior as when loaded

Comment: @PeterHlavatík Look here this is not gonna work because we are showing loader on whole screen so until your all images are loaded you wont be able to scroll collectionView.

Comment: No, I've added loader for each cell in collectionView. At the end it was a better solution to stick with the design pattern. So 5 cells, 5 loaders.